# Chromium Inspect Element causes black screen

Tags: chromium

I am using Chromium Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 13.10 (260972).

When I choose **Inspect Element** from Chromium, Chromium hangs for about 4 seconds and the entire screen (not just Chromium) goes black. I cannot even sleep my PC using power button. Using other button combinations like `Alt + F4` and function keys does not work.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chromium, but the problem still persist. Also, the addons and history of Chromium remains after uninstalling.

I don't whether Ubuntu update or any other factor is the reason behind this?

Is anyone having the same problem as I do?
Also, how the addons and history remained after uninstalling Chromium, and how to remove them?