# Remove Chromium data

Tags: chromium

After not getting any response for my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486257/chromium-inspect-element-causes-black-screen), I think I should uninstall and remove data of Chromium from Ubuntu.

As **uninstalling Chromium does not remove its data** (*like browser history, settings*), I want to know **where are the data of Chromium located** and **how to remove them safely**?

Comment: Try 'apt-get purge chromium-browser'

Comment: Thanks! I think this is one step along with deleting user data from `~/.config/chromium` and now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for chromium will be in one of the hidden directories in hour /home/username folder, either ~/.chromium or somewhere in ~/.config  As I don't have chromium installed, I don't have the exact location.

According to [chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) (which you could have checked yourself) the data is stored at ~/.config/chromium

Comment: Thank you! I uninstalled chromium using `apt-get purge chromium-browser` and deleted user data using your method, and now Chromium is working properly.

Comment: For Ubuntu snap version see `~/snap/chromium/471/.config/chromium` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075103/chromium-config-folder-is-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04